# How to characterize distributions? Specifically how to distinguish discrete uniform distrubitions from normal ones

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, chi-squared-test

I have a bunch of data sets, drawn from different (and unknown) distributions and I want to categorize them so that we can benchmark with a small set of them as "representative" of the actual inputs to the various layers of a neural net.  I am building automated quantization software for such nets.

We have a variety of different hardware we can quantize to and thus we need to route different types of distributions to different "units".   Our main unit handles "bell shaped" curves and also things the are exponential or logarithmic with better precision and fewer bits than floating point.  Still, if the input is a small set of integers (uniform and discrete), that would be a more appropriate representation.  I want to catch those cases.

Next we are applying this to existing neural nets and do not want to completely retrain such nets from scratch.  So, I have only the existing parameters of the nets and activation records to work from.

Many of the data sets look like Gaussian curves (although not always symmetric) whence we can describe them with mean, stddev, tail lengths, etc.  For "bell shaped" distributions, we merely want to shift and scale our distribution such that the majority of data falls in the section of our representation where we have the most precision.  We have a rough idea how to do that.  And we just want to eventually validate that algorithm and develop indicators for when it is operating poorly.  This is not what I am interested in for now.  I want to remove the data sets (e.g. the uniform ones) where the algorithm is not appropriate.

We also have sets that are "clearly" intended to be probablity distributions (all values between zero and one).  Those I hope to pick out due to those limits on the values.  With limited ranges like that, we can adjust our scaling to map onto that set in a relatively precise way.  Again, not an issue for now.

However, we also have occasional data sets drawn from other distributions. In particular, one typical distribution is a small number of discrete integer values (and some of those sets are very small in size, e.g. 1 instance of each value).  And, for what I hope are obvious reasons, I want to categorize those distinctly from either of the above.  We want to send those layers to an "integer" unit, not one operating on logarithmic and bell shaped data and we will use a different algorithm to quantize those, if we do so at all.  They are likely already quantized.

The Chi-square test would seem appropriate for checking that the values are uniform (although further reading suggest the ks test), but I don't know how to use the data to determine the bucket/bin sizes.  This is the main problem I wish to get advice upon.  Note that by the time I get the data, the fact that the original data was integer is lost (other than the fact that the values are actually discrete, but because there are few of them I cannot tell if that is just a sampling artifact).

I am particularly interested in answers where I can use functions from scipy or another Python library to make the determination.  I am using code like the following to catch Gaussian tensors

```py
   if 20 < tensor.size:
       chi, p = scipy.stats.normaltest(tensor)
       if 0.005 < p:
           tensor might be Gaussian
```

Comment: You cannot describe any kind of asymmetry using mean, sd, and kurtosis.  Your question is rather far ranging and obscure, because the distributions you wish to compare have such extremely different characteristics.  Moreover, it's unclear how any such characterization might help with implementing a neural net.  These lead me to suspect the questions you have stated might not be helpful at addressing whatever your underlying statistical problem might be.  Please consider telling us what that original problem is.